# how to retrieve unique value from xml

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i have written a query to retrieve distinct xml node value using foreach 
i am trying to retrive distinct **BankName** and **TemplateModel** from XML
can any one just a better way to write the query with ienumerable or something like that
 
my Xml is as follows

```
<Bank>
<BankName BankName="DohaBank" TemplateModel="CT1">   
  <ChqBasics>      
  </ChqBasics>
  <XandYPosition>       
  </XandYPosition>
</BankName>
<BankName BankName="DohaBank" TemplateModel="CT2">   
  <ChqBasics>       
  </ChqBasics>
  <XandYPosition>        
  </XandYPosition>    
</BankName>  
<BankName BankName="IBQ" TemplateModel="CT1New">
    <ChqBasics>     
  </ChqBasics>
  <XandYPosition>     
  </XandYPosition>
</BankName>
```

**my c# code**

```
 public List<string> bankload()
    {
        List<string> bankname=new List<string>();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("newtest.xml");
       var result= (from item in doc.Descendants("BankName")
                select (string)item.Attribute("BankName")).Distinct();
       foreach (var item in result)
       {
           bankname.Add(item.ToString());
       }
        return bankname;
    }

    public static List<string> templateload(string bankname)
    {
        List<string> templatename = new List<string>();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("newtest.xml");
        var result = (from item in doc.Descendants("BankName")
                      where item.Attribute("BankName").Value == bankname
                      select (string)item.Attribute("TemplateModel")).Distinct();
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            templatename.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        return templatename;
    }
```

i need to bind the result to a combobox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do this?

```
public List<string> bankload()
{
    return
    (
        from item in XDocument.Load("newtest.xml").Descendants("BankName")
        select (string)item.Attribute("BankName")
    )
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
}

public static List<string> templateload(string bankname)
{
    return
    (
        from item in XDocument.Load("newtest.xml").Descendants("BankName")
        where item.Attribute("BankName").Value == bankname
        select (string)item.Attribute("TemplateModel")
    )
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
}
```

---

Do you mean lambdas like this?

```
public List<string> bankload()
{
    return
        XDocument
            .Load("newtest.xml")
            .Descendants("BankName")
            .Select(item => (string)item.Attribute("BankName"))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
}

public static List<string> templateload(string bankname)
{
    return
        XDocument
            .Load("newtest.xml")
            .Descendants("BankName")
            .Where(item => item.Attribute("BankName").Value == bankname)
            .Select(item => (string)item.Attribute("TemplateModel"))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it work. can you please make this code with lamda expression

Comment: Do you mean like that?

Comment: Hai Dear.. Please help me once again. Ihave posted a new question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680640/how-to-update-xml-node-with-linq

Answer (score 0):

Return a list of distinct BankName/TemplateModel combinations in your XML:

```
var result = doc.Descendants("BankName")
                .Select(bn => new
                              {
                                 BankName = bn.Attribute("BankName").Value,
                                 TemplateModel = bn.Attribute("TemplateModel")
                                                   .Value
                              });
```