# how to update xml node with linq

Tags: c#

hai friends i need to update an xml file with node attributes
my xml structure is

```
 <BankName BankName="jinesh" TemplateModel="sam">
<ChqBasics>
  <ChqL>30</ChqL>
  <ChqW>50</ChqW>
  <ChqImgPath>hai</ChqImgPath>
</ChqBasics>
<XandYPosition>
  <column Name="ChqDate" X="10" Y="10" />
  <column Name="CPayAgainst" X="10" Y="10" />
  <column Name="ChqAmtDgt" X="10" Y="10" />
  <column Name="ChqAmtWrds" X="10" Y="10" />
</XandYPosition>
```

i need to update the elements in the **XandYPosition** node so i created a function for this but i am not able to complete this .please help me to achieve this

```
 public static void updatenode(string bankname, string templatemodel,string field,string x,string y)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("newtest.xml");
       var  updatenode = doc
                    .Descendants("BankName")
                    .Where(item => item.Attribute("BankName").Value == bankname && item.Attribute("TemplateModel").Value == templatemodel)
                    .Select(XandYPosition => XandYPosition.Descendants("XandYPosition").Descendants());
    }
```

function call will be like this

```
BasicClass.updatenode(comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, "ChqDate", "1000", "2000");
```

please help to make the code complete

**Upadte:**
How can i update the BankName="Jinesh" with "XYZ"

Comment: What do you want to update in this xml file?

Comment: <column Name="ChqDate" X="10" Y="10" /> to 1000 and 2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, if you get errors please feel free to ask:

```
public static void updatenode(string bankname, string templatemodel,string field,string X,string Y)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("../../newTest.xml");

    IEnumerable<XElement> updatenode = xDoc.Descendants("BankName")
                                           .Where(x => x.Attribute("BankName").Value == bankname && x.Attribute("TemplateModel").Value == templatemodel)
                                           .Select(x => x.Element("XandYPosition").Elements("column")).FirstOrDefault();

    updatenode.Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == field).FirstOrDefault().Attribute("X").Value = X;
    updatenode.Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == field).FirstOrDefault().Attribute("Y").Value = Y;

    xDoc.Save("../../newTest.xml");
}
```

**Note:**

Replace `../../newTest.xml` with the path of your xml file.

**Update:**

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("../../newTest.xml");

XElement updatenode = xDoc.Descendants("BankName")
                                       .Where(x => x.Attribute("BankName").Value == "jinesh" && x.Attribute("TemplateModel").Value == "sam")
                                       .Select(x => x.Element("ChqBasics").Element("ChqL")).FirstOrDefault();

updatenode.Value = "130";

xDoc.Save("../../newTest.xml");
```

For more references please watch these videos on this youtube channel :

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhX-U0Ruy_4eIG8umikVmBrk

Comment: i am getting this error Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Attribute' and no extension method 'Attribute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: now there is some casting errror
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>>' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: casting error remains same. the error first i mention is solved with this code

Comment: Error 6 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Just a minute i will create a sample project and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: wait i will check and say

Comment: Yurekka... Thanks a lot for ur time and effort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64075/discussion-between-jinesh-sam-and-vishal).